# Transforming input text into code

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I'm trying to code a text. I created the code and I put the code to each individual unique character in the text. 
My map now looks like this:

`{{"l", {1, 0}}, {"a", {1, 1}}, {"j", {0, 1, 0}}, {"u", {0, 1, 1}}, {"e", {0, 0}}}`

How do I take these code words and apply them to a text, then put the final text in the output?
Example with this map:

text="lea"

Output: {100011}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a case where an `Association[]` is more appropriate:

```
as = AssociationThread @@ Transpose[{{"l", {1, 0}}, {"a", {1, 1}}, {"j", {0, 1, 0}},
                                     {"u", {0, 1, 1}}, {"e", {0, 0}}}]
```

Then you can do this:

```
StringJoin[Map[IntegerString, Lookup[as, Characters["lea"]], {2}]]
   "100011"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[code] 
code = StringReplace[# -> StringRiffle[#2, ""] & @@@ #]&;
```

***Example:***

```
list = {{"l", {1, 0}}, {"a", {1, 1}}, {"j", {0, 1, 0}}, {"u", {0, 1, 1}}, {"e", {0, 0}}};

code[list]["lea"]
```

> ```
> "100011"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I like J.M.'s solution. But since there is in Mathematica at least 10 ways to do the same thing, I thought to have a go at it

```
code = {{"l", {1, 0}}, {"a", {1, 1}}, {"j", {0, 1, 0}}, {"u", {0, 1, 1}}, {"e", {0, 0}}};
word = "ltea";
let = Characters[word];

StringJoin@Flatten[Cases[code, {x_, y__} /; 
       StringMatchQ[x, #] :> (ToString /@ y)] & /@ let]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
   decode[s_] := Module[{xs, dict, decodeString},
     xs = {{"l", {1, 0}}, {"a", {1, 1}}, {"j", {0, 1, 0}}, {"u", {0, 1, 
      1}}, {"e", {0, 0}}};
     dict = AssociationThread @@ Transpose@xs;
     decodeString[x_] := StringSplit[x, ""] // Map[dict[#] &] // Flatten;
     decodeString[s]
   ]
   decode["lea"]
```

{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}